# Creating dropdown menu and inserting selection into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two tables: events and users.

Events has a column named "event_type".

Users has columns named "event_type_1", "event_type_2", "event_type_3", etc.

I want to create a dropdown menu which will be populated by all event_types (either through the column titles of the users table, or by what's already listed in the event_type column of the events table -- but I don't want them to be repeated).

Then I want the selection (if selected => true) to be inserted into the user table under the event_type column.

I get errors for everything I've tried. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to select the entries under event_type:

<%= collection_select(:race_type, :event_id, Event.all, :id, :race_type) %>

Now I'm just not sure how to insert the selection into @event.race_type. Additionally, I'm not sure how to disallow duplicate listings in the dropdown box (i.e. if there are multiple types of the same name).

Comment: Ok, got the second part: <%= collection_select(:race_type, :event_id, Event.select(:race_type).uniq, :id, :race_type) %> ... now how do I insert the chosen item into the table?

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ldescriptioncountry, class: 'field-label' %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select( :legaldescription, :legalcountry_id, Legalcountry.all, :id, :countryname, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %>
    </div>
</div>`

this will create a drop down menu which will populate as your requirement